# How To Embed Flash Player In Visual Studio.NET (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, flash

How To Use Adobe Flash Player In Visual Studio.NET (VB.NET)
i have a SWF file will be created by Micromedia Flash Player , when i want to use this SWF file in Visual Studio Web Form , I do not see a component in toolbox to use my SWF file in web site
how to use my SWF file in VB.NET ? Which By Tools ?
Thanks

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30512/How-To-Play-SWF-File-In-Asp-Net

Comment: Have you tried searching Google?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a WinForms application, and you want it on a form, your best bet is probably to use a WebBrowser control and essentially create the webpage you want to display in it as HTML.